Ubuntu 22.04 and Ruby 3.1.4
How to install Ruby 3.1.4 on Ubunt 22.04 via rvm?
When I try to list ruby versions the highest version is
3.0.0
rvm list known


I need 3.1.4
How to install Ruby 3.1.4 on Ubuntu 22.04?

Why don't you install via snap?

To install the ruby 3.34 snap package in Ubuntu 22.04 open the terminal and type:
sudo snap install ruby --classic

Alternatively you can install the ruby 3.16 snap package with the following command.
sudo snap install ruby --channel=3.1/stable --classic

To list all the available ruby snap package versions:
snap info ruby

